# How to formulate a generalized linear mixed model?

Tags: r, glmm

I have a data set like this:
population: numeric
country: categorical
city: categorical, nested in country
century: categorical, crossed by city and country
year: categorical, nested in century, crossed by city and country

I would like to know if population is significantly affected by all the other variables. Is the following code right?

```
>library (lme4)
>glmm<-glmer(population~city*country*year*century+(1|century/year)+(1|country/city)*+(1|year*country/city)+(1|century*country/city),family=poisson)
```

Comment: Your model is overly complex. Perhaps you should start first by formulating your research question with more details, and giving more information for the nature of your response variable.

Comment: what do you understand by all other vriables ...

Comment: I have better understanding on GLMM now. Thank you all the same.